# Return BOOLEAN value if item EXISTS in SQLITE database

Tags: sqlite

I need to return a boolean value TRUE or FALSE if a row exists in a database. Nothing else.
With the code below no boolean is ever returned! What is the correct syntax?

```
$EntryExistsBoolean = $db->query("SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE company=SmartCo");

if ($EntryExistsBoolean === false)
    {
        echo "Item does not exist in the database";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Item found in the database";
    }
```

Comment: You are currently retrieving the field "name" which I guess is not a boolean from your query. You just need to test if your query result contains at least 1 row. And you can then simplify your query to ```SELECT name FRON myTable WHERE name = 'SmartCo'```

Comment: Yes, it is not a boolean. I don't want to retrieve the field name indeed... Could you please clarify what the complete query string should be?

Answer (score 2):

Your current query has a syntax problem, because the string literal does not have proper quotes.  I would use this query though:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE company = 'SmartCo')
```

This would return should there be at least one record in your table where the company is `SmartCo`.  Otherwise, it would return false.

```
$sql = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE company = 'SmartCo')";
$EntryExistsBoolean = $db->query($sql);
if ($EntryExistsBoolean === false) {
    echo "Item does not exist in the database";
}
else {
    echo "Item found in the database";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something simpler:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE company = 'SmartCo'
```

and then examine the returned integer to find out if there are 0, 1 (or more) companies with that name

Comment: Even with an index on company?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite a Boolean value is either `1` or `0`.
So all you need is:

```
SELECT MAX(company='SmartCo') AS bool FROM myTable
```

If all you want is to get a row when the value is there or no row if the value is not there then it's simpler:

```
SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE company='SmartCo'
```

Comment: It always returns TRUE even if the item does not exist

Comment: No it does not return true if the item does not exist. You are doing something wrong. `company='SmartCo'` returns 0 if the value is not there.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sA3RsDUpXMLCdv24rhDXZL/0

Comment: Then I must be doing something wrong in the evaluation statement.                                   $sql = "SELECT MAX(company='SmartCo) AS bool FROM myTable";

    $EntryExistsBoolean = $db->query($sql);
    
    if ($EntryExistsBoolean === 0)
    {
        echo "Record does not exist";
    }
    else {
        echo "Item found in the database"; //Always returns this
    }

Comment: My query is:        $sql = "SELECT MAX(company='SmartCo') AS bool FROM myTable";
 $EntryExistsBoolean = $db->query($sql);

Comment: Also like this the statement is never FALSE